# Can't click element inside iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe, click

On the screenhsot below is HTML-code of iframe.

The first two red marked object can be identified by Webdriver however the last marked (which is a button) can't be clicked by Webdriver. I have tried click it using different ways (like click by id, name, etc). But I still can't click the submit button.

Please help me to click that submit button inside the frame.
[image]

Comment: Is there code how you are performing the click? How about posting the error?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `switchTo().frame()` to access content within a `frame` or `iframe`.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name");  // where name is the name of the iframe i.e. name="frameName", you would use framename
driver.switchTo().frame(0);       // You can switch to the frame by index
driver.switchTo().frame(element); // You can switch to the frame by a WebElement reference
```

In your particular case you can use:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("InstantSgn");
```

To switch out of the frame after you're done within the `iframe` context:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me today. It might be simply due to you not switching to the frame, or it could be something I experienced.

This happened to me in IE only. In Chrome there is no problem at all.

[Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXTHK.png)

As you can see, I did switch to the frame to make sure this element could be found. But, it could not be. The only solution that I found was to put Thread.Sleep(2000) to make it pass. I am not quite sure why, but I guess it has something to do with the content not being available in the DOM.

Comment: Please modify your answer to include the code as formatted text, rather than an image.